# Organize routes in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I start to look at Node.js. Also I'm using Express.
And I have a question - how can I organize web application routes? All examples just put all this `app.get/post/put()` handlers in app.js and it works just fine. This is good but if I have something more than a simple HW Blog? Is it possible to do something like this:

```
var app = express.createServer();
app.get( '/module-a/*', require('./module-a').urls );
app.get( '/module-b/*', require('./module-b').urls );
```

and

```
// file: module-a.js
urls.get('/:id', function(req, res){...}); // <- assuming this is handler for /module-a/1
```

In other words - I'd like something like Django's URLConf but in Node.js.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check out the examples here:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples

'mvc' and 'route-separation' may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! This gives me some ideas. Especially 'mvc' one.

Comment: This answer should go into more depth.. it's a link only answer.. the answer by @Vegar is far more in depth

Answer (score 96):

I found a short example in ´[Smashing Node.js: JavaScript Everywhere](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781119963103/chapter-9-express/navpoint65)´ that I really liked.

By defining `module-a` and `module-b` as its own express applications, you can mount them into the main application as you like by using connects [app.use( )](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/gh-pages/tests.md#appuse) :

**module-a.js**

```
module.exports = function(){
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();

  app.get('/:id', function(req, res){...});

  return app;
}();
```

**module-b.js**

```
module.exports = function(){
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();

  app.get('/:id', function(req, res){...});

  return app;
}();
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.configure(..);

app.get('/', ....)
app.use('/module-a', require('./module-a'));    
app.use('/where/ever', require('./module-b'));    

app.listen(3000);
```

This would give you the routes

```
localhost:3000/
localhost:3000/module-a/:id
localhost:3000/where/ever/:id
```

Comment: As I said: This is taken from Guillermo Rauchs book, so I'll just blame him for all potential mind damage :-)

Comment: By this approach, `app`, `module-a`, `module-b` all get it's own *express app* instance, is this good?

Comment: The book does not mention any down sides. I would guess that having multiple application instances will take more resources then not having multiple instances, but how much? And I suppose it would be possible to overuse this method too. I wouldn't make every little route its own application, but if the application consist of multiple separated concerns, like a blog and a web store, I find it quite neat.

Comment: You can DRY this up by passing in your express app as a param.  Then, you don't need to make multiple express applications.  Setup like this: `module.exports = function(app) {...}` and then just call `app.use('/module-a', require('./module-a')(app));

Comment: @mattmc3, your solution gives me the following error: Error: Cyclic \_\_proto\_\_ value

Comment: @mattmc3 I think it should be a bit more like this: `module-b.exports = function(app){ return function(){ app.get('/:id',function(req, res){...}); return app; }; }; app.use('/where/ever', require('./module-b')(app));`

Comment: In the express 4 somethings have changed. I have found this article what solve my migration problems http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4.

Comment: I had problems with that link. But i think this one works: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4

Comment: Notice that: 
(1) `app.use('/prefix', router)` works fine;
(2) node files run into a closure.
Thus, quite simply cut your routes from the main file and paste them into their own `./app/my-component/routes.js`, top it with `router = require('express').Router();`, and bottom it with `module.exports = router`. Then, in main add: `app.use('/prefix', require('./app/my-component/routes'))`.

Comment: setup router module: module.exports = function(express){ var router = express.Router(); .... return router }; 
setup app: app.use('/module-a/', require('./module-a/')(express));

Answer (score 8):

There also is a screencast of @tjholowaychuk (creator of express) where he uses the method @Vegar described.

#### Available on Vimeo: [Modular web applications with Node.js and Express](https://vimeo.com/56166857)

Answer (score 3):

One more alternative;

App.js

```
var express = require('express')
      , routes = require('./routes')
      , user = require('./routes/user')
      , http = require('http')
      , path = require('path');

    var app = express();


// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);


app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users/:id', user.getUser);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

index.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

user.js

```
exports.getUser = function(req, res){


    //your code to get user

};
```

Comment: Shouldn't you require('./index") ?

Comment: @Kokodoko If index.js is inside the routes directory, then `require('./routes')` will actually be requiring `./routes/index`. It looks for index.js file inside that folder.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [the article](https://medium.com/node-js-zone/d4fced62118d) about [the **express-routescan** node module](https://github.com/anotheri/express-routescan). This module helps to organize maintainable routing for express application. You can try it. This is the best solution for me.

Comment: Of course it's the best solution for you; you wrote it ;) But honestly though, it is a very nice module!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do:

1:

```
module1(app.route('/route1'));
module2(app.route('/route2'));
```

In the modules you can just implement 1 function to handle the http methods:

```
module.exports = function(route) {
   route
   .get(function(req, res, next) {
       ...
   }).
   .post(function(req, res, next) {
      ...
   });
}
```

2: if you want to handle the route by a sub-app instead of a module/middleware :

```
var m1 = require(module1.js);
var m2 = require(module2.js);

app.use('/route1', r1);
app.use('/route2', r2);
```