# Using routes in Express-js

Tags: node.js, url-routing, express

So I'm starting to use Node.js. I saw the video with Ryan Dahl on [Nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/) and heard he recommended Express-js for websites.

I downloaded the latest version of Express, and began to code. I have a fully fledged static view up on /, but as soon as I try sending parameters, I get errors like this:

```
Cannot GET /wiki
```

I tried following the guide on [expressjs.com](http://expressjs.com/) but the way one uses routes has changed in the latest version, which makes the guide unusable.

Guide:

```
app.get('/users/:id?', function(req, res, next){
    var id = req.params.id;
    if (id) {
        // do something
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Generated by Express:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

My problem arises when I try and add another route.

```
app.get('/wiki', routes.wiki_show);
```

I've tried a bunch of approaches, but I keep getting the `Cannot GET /wiki` (404) error.

routes/index.js looks like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Test', articles: articles, current_article: current_article, sections: sections })
};
```

The only thing I did there was add some parameters (arrays in the same file) and this i working. But when I copy the contents and change `exports.index` to `exports.wiki` or `exports.wiki_show` I still get the `Cannot GET /wiki` error.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm missing here? - Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the router middleware?

Comment: You downloaded the lastest Express? Did you get it from github or through NPM?

Comment: @DeaDEnD Yes, I'm quite sure of that :)

Comment: @RyanOlds I got it from GitHub :)

Comment: Master isn't stable. Install it using NPM, you should get 2.5.6. Also, the router middleware is automatically bound when you specify a route.

Comment: Thanks @RyanOlds - I just installed it through NPM, and this seems way more stable.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

So, after I created my question, I got this related list on the right with a similar issue: [Organize routes in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602212/organize-routes-in-node-js).

The answer in that post linked to the [Express repo on GitHub](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master) and suggests to look at the '[route-separation](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/route-separation)' example.

This helped me change my code, and I now have it working. - Thanks for your comments.

My implementation ended up looking like this;

I require my routes in the app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , site = require('./site')
  , wiki = require('./wiki');
```

And I add my routes like this:

```
app.get('/', site.index);
app.get('/wiki/:id', wiki.show);
app.get('/wiki/:id/edit', wiki.edit);
```

I have two files called wiki.js and site.js in the root of my app, containing this:

```
exports.edit = function(req, res) {

    var wiki_entry = req.params.id;

    res.render('wiki/edit', {
        title: 'Editing Wiki',
        wiki: wiki_entry
    })
}
```

Comment: Express is great.  As a beginner, it's also useful to build a web server from the ground up once to understand node.  I found a tutorial here which I went through then went straight to express:  http://nodebeginner.org/

Answer (score 10):

The [route-map](https://github.com/BernadineComputing/express/blob/master/examples/route-map/index.js) express example matches url paths with objects which in turn matches http verbs with functions. This lays the routing out in a tree, which is concise and easy to read. The apps's entities are also written as objects with the functions as enclosed methods.

```
var express = require('../../lib/express')
  , verbose = process.env.NODE_ENV != 'test'
  , app = module.exports = express();

app.map = function(a, route){
  route = route || '';
  for (var key in a) {
    switch (typeof a[key]) {
      // { '/path': { ... }}
      case 'object':
        app.map(a[key], route + key);
        break;
      // get: function(){ ... }
      case 'function':
        if (verbose) console.log('%s %s', key, route);
        app[key](route, a[key]);
        break;
    }
  }
};

var users = {
  list: function(req, res){
    res.send('user list');
  },

  get: function(req, res){
    res.send('user ' + req.params.uid);
  },

  del: function(req, res){
    res.send('delete users');
  }
};

var pets = {
  list: function(req, res){
    res.send('user ' + req.params.uid + '\'s pets');
  },

  del: function(req, res){
    res.send('delete ' + req.params.uid + '\'s pet ' + req.params.pid);
  }
};

app.map({
  '/users': {
    get: users.list,
    del: users.del,
    '/:uid': {
      get: users.get,
      '/pets': {
        get: pets.list,
        '/:pid': {
          del: pets.del
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems that only index.js get loaded when you require("./routes") .
I used the following code in index.js to load the rest of the routes:

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , path = require('path');

fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(function(file){
  var route_fname = __dirname + '/' + file;
  var route_name = path.basename(route_fname, '.js');
  if(route_name !== 'index' && route_name[0] !== "."){ 
    exports[route_name] = require(route_fname)[route_name];
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a nice way to avoid having a ton of `require` statements if you're not grouping your routes by a sort of namespace.

Comment: Actually, changing the ~last line to `exports[route_name] = require(route_fname)` makes it so you can later refer to routes by a namespace, e.g. `routes.users.show`.

Answer (score 4):

You could also organise them into modules. So it would be something like.

```
./
controllers
    index.js
    indexController.js
app.js
```

and then in the indexController.js of the controllers export your controllers.

```
//indexController.js
module.exports = function(){
//do some set up

var self = {
     indexAction : function (req,res){
       //do your thing
}
return self;
};
```

then in index.js of controllers dir

```
exports.indexController = require("./indexController");
```

and finally in app.js

```
var controllers = require("./controllers");

app.get("/",controllers.indexController().indexAction);
```

I think this approach allows for clearer seperation and also you can configure your controllers by passing perhaps a db connection in.

Answer (score 1):

## No one should ever have to keep writing app.use('/someRoute', require('someFile')) until it forms a heap of code.

It just doesn't make sense at all to be spending time invoking/defining routings. Even if you do need custom control, it's probably only for some of the time, and for the most bit you want to be able to just create a standard file structure of routings and have a module do it automatically.

Try [Route Magic](https://github.com/calvintwr/express-routemagic)

As you scale your app, the routing invocations will start to form a giant heap of code that serves no purpose. You want to do just 2 lines of code to handle all the `app.use` routing invocations with Route Magic like this:

```js
const magic = require('express-routemagic')
magic.use(app, __dirname, '[your route directory]')
```

For those you want to handle manually, just don't use pass the directory to Magic.