# How handle routes in Express.js

Tags: express

how to handle Routes in Express.js and how many ways to handle that kindly inform me with code and demo.answer will be appreciated.thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using routes in Express-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864626/using-routes-in-express-js)

Answer (score 2):

I've written [a longer guide that explains this stuff](http://evanhahn.com/understanding-express-js/), but here's a simple example:

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.get("/", function(request, response) {
  response.send("Welcome to the homepage!");
});

app.get("/about", function(request, response) {
  response.send("Welcome to the about page!");
});

app.get("*", function(request, response) {
  response.send("404!");
});

app.listen(1337);
```