# how to get id from url in express, param and query doesnt seem to work

Tags: node.js, express

I have a url, i'm trying to get id but none of it is working req.params nor req.query

```
app.get('/test/:uid', function testfn(req, res, next) {
  debug('uid', req.params.uid);  // gives :uid
  debug('uid', req.query.uid);  // gives undefined      
});
```

I'm doing an ajax call like this

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.testlink', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/test/:uid',
    success: function(var) {
      console.log('success');
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('Error occured');
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

I'm using

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

instead of body parser

Comment: In your code, `app.get('test/uid:', test.collect);` should be `app.get('test/:uid', test.collect);`. Then you can use `req.params.uid` to get the uid value.

Comment: hi sorry, it is like that only, i made mistake while posting the question. Still its not taking the value

Comment: Again in your code, you are using `req.param` instead of using `req.params`.

Comment: I'm doing

debug('uid', req.param.uid);  // which gives :uid when debugged

Comment: It seems that you should use `test` instead of `test.collect` as the route handler function.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Your code is working as expected: The `ajax` call specifies `url: '/test/:uid'` which is what puts `:uid` in `req.params.uid`.

Try sending something else: `url: '/test/123'` and `req.params.uid` will contain `123`

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example that will work.  I will give step by step instructions from the start:

```
express myproject
cd myproject
npm install
```

Open app.js and add in the following somewhere in the file - maybe right before the line `app.get('/test/:uid',test);`

```
var test = function(req,res,next) {
  // do whatever logic is needed 
  res.end('Displaying information for uid ' + req.params.uid);
}
app.get('/test/:uid',test);
```

Now, open up a new terminal, make sure you are in the myproject directory and enter:

```
node app.js
```

Now you can visit `http://localhost:3000/test/45` on the local machine and you should see:

```
Displaying information for uid 45
```

If you are not accessing from your local machine make sure to change the url above to match whatever server your node app is running on.

Also, this is just a simple example. You might be better off organizing everything by placing the routes in files similar to the routes directory example setup in a new install of an express app.  You can find more detailed examples of this on the web like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602212/organize-routes-in-node-js) one and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864626/using-routes-in-express-js) one.  Also, one of the best explanations of organizing/reusing code in Node this I have seen is in the book NodeJS in Action.